# Incorporate Triggers Into the Model

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have created a data model with in EF 4.0, however I am not sure how I can capture things like Triggers in this model so that if others were to deploy it the Tables, Views, Triggers, etc would go along with it.  Is there a way to pull triggers into the model build?

Thanks!

--B

Comment: Is it necessary to capture the triggers from the database? Would putting event handlers on your entities work for what you're trying to do? It's definitely not the same thing, but it might do the job depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks Justin...I think we will be tracking these outside of the DB

Comment: Guess I should have added it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting event handlers on your entities is definitely not the same thing, but it might do the job depending on what you need. Some references I've used for this if you need them:

[How to: Execute Business Logic During Scalar Property Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716747.aspx)

[How to: Execute Business Logic When the Object State Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705449.aspx)

[How to: Execute Business Logic When Saving Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx)

[Entity Framework (EF) – Events](http://romiller.com/2009/06/28/entity-framework-events/) (this one's pretty good)

Not sure if you've already done what you wanted to do, but HTH.

**Edit:** One dumb mistake I made: Watch out for infinite loops if you use an OnPropertyChanged or OnPropertyChanging event to alter another property (in my case, it was MyEntity.DateModified).